# RequireJs: How to configure object after load

Tags: requirejs

I have requireJs config

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js',
    shim: {
        plugin: {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'Plugin'
        }
    },
    paths: {
        unq: 'somefolder/Plugin'
    }
});
```

How I can set extra parameters for loaded plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I think the variables "unq" in the paths and "plugin" in the shim should match if you want the shim to apply to that file.

Let's say you changed the plugin variable to "unq."  You just have to load "unq" into your require js module as a dependency, and use the exported variable "Plugin" to set parameters, etc.